# Error deploying gwt app ("Exception in flushing batch payload")

Tags: google-app-engine, batch-file, gwt, oauth

I feel I have exceeded any quota, but quota on `appengine` site seems to be OK... Which limit did I exceed?

In detail I had the following output:

```
Deploying:
    Uploading 194 files.
    Uploaded 48 files.
    Sending batch containing 30 blob(s) totaling 3079KB.
    Sending batch containing 31 blob(s) totaling 3225KB.
    Sending batch containing 32 blob(s) totaling 3395KB.
    Sending batch containing 33 blob(s) totaling 3438KB.
    Sending batch containing 34 blob(s) totaling 3519KB.
    Sending batch containing 35 blob(s) totaling 3665KB.
    Sending batch containing 36 blob(s) totaling 3835KB.
    Sending batch containing 37 blob(s) totaling 3886KB.
    Sending batch containing 38 blob(s) totaling 3930KB.
    Sending batch containing 39 blob(s) totaling 3934KB.
    Sending batch containing 40 blob(s) totaling 4017KB.
    Sending batch containing 41 blob(s) totaling 4163KB.
    Sending batch containing 42 blob(s) totaling 4332KB.
    Sending batch containing 43 blob(s) totaling 4375KB.
    Sending batch containing 44 blob(s) totaling 4457KB.
    Sending batch containing 45 blob(s) totaling 4603KB.
    Sending batch containing 46 blob(s) totaling 4773KB.
    Sending batch containing 47 blob(s) totaling 4817KB.
    Sending batch containing 48 blob(s) totaling 4898KB.
    Sending batch containing 49 blob(s) totaling 5043KB.
    Sending batch containing 50 blob(s) totaling 5198KB.
    Sending batch containing 51 blob(s) totaling 5241KB.
    Sending batch containing 52 blob(s) totaling 5325KB.
    Sending batch containing 53 blob(s) totaling 5470KB.
    Sending batch containing 54 blob(s) totaling 5639KB.
    Sending batch containing 55 blob(s) totaling 5683KB.
    Sending batch containing 56 blob(s) totaling 5763KB.
    Sending batch containing 57 blob(s) totaling 5909KB.
    Sending batch containing 58 blob(s) totaling 6078KB.
    Sending batch containing 59 blob(s) totaling 6159KB.
    Sending batch containing 60 blob(s) totaling 6304KB.
    Sending batch containing 61 blob(s) totaling 6459KB.
    Sending batch containing 62 blob(s) totaling 6510KB.
    Sending batch containing 63 blob(s) totaling 6553KB.
    Sending batch containing 64 blob(s) totaling 6558KB.
    Sending batch containing 65 blob(s) totaling 6641KB.
    Uploaded 96 files.
    Sending batch containing 40 file(s) totaling 3112KB.
    Sending batch containing 41 file(s) totaling 3281KB.
    Sending batch containing 42 file(s) totaling 3332KB.
    Sending batch containing 43 file(s) totaling 3375KB.
    Uploaded 144 files.
    Sending batch containing 44 file(s) totaling 3380KB.
    Sending batch containing 45 file(s) totaling 3461KB.
    Sending batch containing 46 file(s) totaling 3606KB.
    Sending batch containing 47 file(s) totaling 3776KB.
    Sending batch containing 48 file(s) totaling 3827KB.
    Sending batch containing 49 file(s) totaling 3871KB.
    Sending batch containing 50 file(s) totaling 3875KB.
    Sending batch containing 51 file(s) totaling 3957KB.
    Sending batch containing 52 file(s) totaling 4103KB.
    Sending batch containing 53 file(s) totaling 4272KB.
    Sending batch containing 54 file(s) totaling 4324KB.
    Sending batch containing 55 file(s) totaling 4367KB.
    Sending batch containing 56 file(s) totaling 4372KB.
    Sending batch containing 57 file(s) totaling 4454KB.
    Sending batch containing 58 file(s) totaling 4600KB.
    Sending batch containing 59 file(s) totaling 4769KB.
    Sending batch containing 60 file(s) totaling 4820KB.
    Sending batch containing 61 file(s) totaling 4863KB.
    Sending batch containing 62 file(s) totaling 4868KB.
    Sending batch containing 63 file(s) totaling 4950KB.
    Sending batch containing 64 file(s) totaling 5096KB.
    Sending batch containing 65 file(s) totaling 5266KB.
    Sending batch containing 66 file(s) totaling 5317KB.
    Sending batch containing 67 file(s) totaling 5361KB.
    Sending batch containing 68 file(s) totaling 5365KB.
    Sending batch containing 69 file(s) totaling 5446KB.
    Sending batch containing 70 file(s) totaling 5592KB.
    Sending batch containing 71 file(s) totaling 5747KB.
    Sending batch containing 72 file(s) totaling 5798KB.
    Sending batch containing 73 file(s) totaling 5841KB.
    Sending batch containing 74 file(s) totaling 5846KB.
    Sending batch containing 75 file(s) totaling 5929KB.
    Sending batch containing 76 file(s) totaling 6075KB.
    Sending batch containing 77 file(s) totaling 6244KB.
    Exception in flushing batch payload, so sending 1 by 1...Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/addfiles?=&app_id=r-logix&version=8&
401 Unauthorized
Invalid OAuth token

    Rolling back the update.
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.RemoteIOException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/rollback?app_id=r-logix&version=8&
401 Unauthorized
Invalid OAuth token


Debugging information may be found in C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine-deploy9008468223746869532.log
```

Later I got the following error:

Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/deploy?app_id=r-logix&version=4&
400 Bad Request

Client Error (400)
The request is invalid for an unspecified reason.

```
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:293)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:253)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:232)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.LoggingClientDeploySender.send(LoggingClientDeploySender.java:47)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:987)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.deploy(AppVersionUpload.java:844)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.commit(AppVersionUpload.java:775)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:115)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:473)
at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:55)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:158)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Comment: is there anything useful in appengine-deploy9008468223746869532.log?

Comment: The file does no longer exist. I will try again and look for such file immediately afterwards.

Comment: What I remember now is that, recently, I have been experimenting with multiple modules in one web app. Therefore I have added 2 more modules, but now I am using only one of them again. Perhaps, the additional modules let the upload explode somehow?

Comment: Later after I have removed some versions from my app at appengine, I got the error that I have added at the end of my report.

Comment: Meanwhile, I have found out that the following line which reduces the number of GWT compile permutations from 15 (3 langs times 5 user agents) to 3 (3 langs times 1 user agent) fixes the problem. But the overall amount of data being uploaded is by far below the limit of 1GB... So I do not quite understand the reason of the problem...

Comment: Meanwhile I have a new theory. I think that with all these permutations the upload process takes so long that this so-called "OAuth" token expires before the upload process has finished. Is this possible? Does anybody know when this token times out? Please help me I really need to upload a version within few days with all permutations... Is there a possibility to upload some permutations in one step and the remaining ones in another step? There must be any solution, actually, right? :) Please don't tell me that I have to drop GWT/GAE just because I cannot upload larger projects...

Comment: Now, I have seen that the upload always fails after exactly one hour. So, I think the token expires after 1 hour. What can I do to decrease the upload time without cutting the number of GWT compile permutations that I need?

Comment: I saw similiar problem recently.  Mine was actually working yesterday but didn't work today after I added probably 300 java files.  now I saw:  Preparing to deploy:
 Created staging directory at: 'C:\blah.tmp'
 Scanning for jsp files.
 Scanning files on local disk.
 Scanned 250 files.
 Initiating update.
 Cloning 2 static files.
 Cloning 291 application files.

Deploying:
 Uploading 105 files.
 Uploaded 26 files.
 Uploaded 52 files.
 Uploaded 78 files.
 Sending batch containing 100 file(s) totaling 320KB.

Comment: My recent impression is, that deployment is working or not working arbitrarily. Most often, I get errors like "Unexpected error" or "unknown internal error". Would really like to know what is going wrong with app engine recently. Update to google eclipse plugin SDK 1.9.5 is also not working...

Comment: Did you also upgraded the GWT SDK to 2.6 or above, at that time ?

Comment: I ran across this old question of mine. If anybody cares. This project was canceled because the issues with GWT and appengine were just a little bit too many. ;-)